# Modal inside of a div

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Basically my modal is inside my div, but i want it outside of it... the problem is i am making use of a foreach statement aswell so it needs to be inside the foreach statement but also outside of the content div.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="block block-rounded block-fx-pop block-themed">
      <div class="block-header bg-gd-sublime">
          <h3 class="block-title">Manage subscription plans</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="block-content block-content-full">
          <!-- DataTables init on table by adding .js-dataTable-full class, functionality is initialized in js/pages/be_tables_datatables.min.js which was auto compiled from _es6/pages/be_tables_datatables.js -->
          <table class="table js-dataTable-full">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th style="font-size: 12px;">Subscription name</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Color</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Price</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">duration</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Account/day</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Accounts type</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Private</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Users</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $getPlans = $odb->query('SELECT * FROM plans ORDER BY price ASC');
                foreach ($getPlans as $dPlans) {
                  if ($dPlans['private'] == 0) { $private = 'No'; } else { $private = 'Yes'; }
                  $id = $dPlans['ID'];
                  $getpeople = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `users` WHERE `membership` = '$id'");
                  $fetchpeople = $getpeople->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  $people = $fetchpeople['total'];
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <a class="link-fx" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter<?php echo $id; ?>"><?=$dPlans['name']?></a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-circle" style='color:<?=$dPlans['color']?>'></i></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['price']?> €</td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['length']?> <?=$dPlans['unit']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['limit']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['accounts']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$private?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$people?></td>
                  </tr>
                  

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Plan: <?=$dPlans['name']?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post">
                                  <div class="block-content">
                                    <div class="row items-push">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-username">Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" name="name<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['name']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-email">Price</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price2" name="price<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['price']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Duration</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="length<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['length']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-skill">Time unit <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="unit<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                    <option value="Days" <?php echo selectedUnit('Days',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Days</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Weeks" <?php echo selectedUnit('Weeks',$dPlans['unit']); ?> >Week</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Months" <?php echo selectedUnit('Months',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Month</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Years" <?php echo selectedUnit('Years',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Year</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Account per day</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="limit<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['limit']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Account type</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="accounts<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['accounts']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-skill">Private <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="private<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                  <option value="1" <?php echo selectedUnit(1,$dPlans['private']); ?>>Yes</option>
                                                  <option value="0" <?php echo selectedUnit(0,$dPlans['private']); ?>>No</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button name="update" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                <?php }
                ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried moving/adding divs but no change and it still displays like this:
[image]

I know my formating is really bad.

What Yasir Suggested me to do:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="block block-rounded block-fx-pop block-themed">
      <div class="block-header bg-gd-sublime">
          <h3 class="block-title">Manage subscription plans</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="block-content block-content-full">
          <!-- DataTables init on table by adding .js-dataTable-full class, functionality is initialized in js/pages/be_tables_datatables.min.js which was auto compiled from _es6/pages/be_tables_datatables.js -->
          <table class="table js-dataTable-full">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th style="font-size: 12px;">Subscription name</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Price</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Duration</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Account/day</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Accounts type</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;">Users</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $getPlans = $odb->query('SELECT * FROM plans ORDER BY price ASC');
                foreach ($getPlans as $dPlans) {
                  if ($dPlans['private'] == 0) { $private = 'No'; } else { $private = 'Yes'; }
                  $id = $dPlans['ID'];
                  $getpeople = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `users` WHERE `membership` = '$id'");
                  $fetchpeople = $getpeople->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  $people = $fetchpeople['total'];
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <a class="link-fx" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter<?php echo $id; ?>"><?=$dPlans['name']?></a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['price']?> €</td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['length']?> <?=$dPlans['unit']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['limit']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$dPlans['accounts']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px;"><?=$people?></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                <?php }
                ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

                <?php
                $getPlans = $odb->query('SELECT * FROM plans ORDER BY price ASC');
                foreach ($getPlans as $dPlans) {
                  if ($dPlans['private'] == 0) { $private = 'No'; } else { $private = 'Yes'; }
                  $id = $dPlans['ID'];
                  $getpeople = $odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `users` WHERE `membership` = '$id'");
                  $fetchpeople = $getpeople->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  $people = $fetchpeople['total'];
                  ?>
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Plan: <?=$dPlans['name']?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post">
                                  <div class="block-content">
                                    <div class="row items-push">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-username">Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" name="name<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['name']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-email">Price</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price2" name="price<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['price']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Duration</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="length<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['length']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-skill">Time unit <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="unit<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                    <option value="Days" <?php echo selectedUnit('Days',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Days</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Weeks" <?php echo selectedUnit('Weeks',$dPlans['unit']); ?> >Week</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Months" <?php echo selectedUnit('Months',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Month</option>
                                                                                                <option value="Years" <?php echo selectedUnit('Years',$dPlans['unit']); ?>>Year</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Account per day</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="limit<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['limit']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-password">Account type</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length2" name="accounts<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?=$dPlans['accounts']?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="val-skill">Private <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="private<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                  <option value="1" <?php echo selectedUnit(1,$dPlans['private']); ?>>Yes</option>
                                                  <option value="0" <?php echo selectedUnit(0,$dPlans['private']); ?>>No</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button name="update" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<?php }
  ?>
```

Comment: Just showing us an image of how you _don't_ want it to look doesn't give us anything to go on. How do you _want_ it to look? We also don't know how you've structured your overall HTML or what your CSS looks like.

Comment: Well you can see that the modal itself is inside of the DIV named content, and that it produces a scrollbar on the right. What i want is that the modal should be on TOP of the div class content, like outside of it so it doesnt produce a scrollbar on the right.

Comment: You have multiple modals on that page, you might want to take a look at Bootstrap's [varying-modal-content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Comment: For this you have to execute your same query and foreach loop two times. One inside the table and one outside the div with all modals.

Comment: @YasirMushtaq Did what you said and moved it outside of the div, and then made another foreach statement, it works for first plan "trial" but when i click second one it just makes the screen darker in the background but doesn't open a modal.